# how to make a header fixed while content is scrolled

Tags: html, css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to make header & tab fixed while the main content is scrolled. Since those 2 header images & html tab is placed within page `<content>`. It scrolls. But how to make it fixed in its position?. Or is there any alternate solution to put the header out of page's content?.  Here is my code

```
    <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="budgetspend.controller.App" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
displayBlock="true">
<App id="BA_APP">
    <pages>
        <Page>
            <content>
                <Image class="logo" src="../images/logo_new.png"/>
                <Image class="header" src="../images/header-bg.png"/>
                <html:ul class="tab">
                    <html:li>
                        <html:a id="onBud" class="tablinks active">Budget Analyzer</html:a>
                    </html:li>
                    <html:li>
                        <html:a id="onSpend" class="tablinks">Spend Analyzer</html:a>
                    </html:li>
                </html:ul>
                <sap.ui.layout:VerticalLayout xmlns:sap.ui.layout="sap.ui.layout" id="budget_layt" class="lay_cont">
                    <sap.ui.layout:content>  .............
```

> NOTE : Header image & tab covers almost 130px. so I can't place it inside `<headerContent>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the content part of the page (which is now a `VerticalLayout`) into a `sap.m.ScrollContainer`, which provides scrolling capabilities to its content. With this, you can scroll the content inside the container. You can set a custom height to the scroll container.

Have you tried to implement an `sap.m.IconTabBar` control instead of creating HTML elements in the XML view?

Comment: Thanks !! I have used `<ScrollContainer>` on XML View & it worked. Yes, I have tried using `sap.m.IconTabBar`. But I was just exploring how standard HTML works on SAPUI5.